# Is nexus able to provide artifacts of not configured repositories?

Tags: nexus

I am using nexus on our companies build server as proxy. Sometimes developers add new dependencies to their projects without telling me. Hence, the list of proxy repositories is sometimes not in sync what is really required. As a result, the jobs in our jenkins build server fail because of missing artificats. The jenkins is configured to use the nexus proxy repositories.

Is it possible to tell nexus to download the artifacts from the original repository if it is not found in the proxied ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that developers add repository entries into their Maven pom file to get further dependencies and/or modify their settings.xml.

On the other hand the CI server is configured to get everything from Nexus with mirrorOf *.

There is no automatic addition of repositories based on this setup. You can do two things imho

- create scripts that do that for you using the Nexus REST API
- or educate your developers to tell you to add the proxy repos to Nexus

Potentially you can even use the [Maven enforcer rule to disallow repositories](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireNoRepositories.html) in the POM and set up an explicit message and allow them to create proxy repositories in Nexus. Just dont forget to have them added to the group you are using on the CI server.